# What does the quick_search_mode config option in midnight commander do?

Tags: mc

Came across an option in mc's .ini file: `quick_search_mode=2`. What does this do? Didn't find anything online or in the man page.

I am trying to configure the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> quick search function to search case insensitive, so was wondering if that is the option to configure that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This corresponds to the “Use panel sort mode” in the “Quick search” section of the panel options:

[image: Screenshot of the panel options, with “Use panel sort mode” highlighted]

This causes quick searches to use the “Case sensitive” setting of the panel in which they’re performed; you’ll find this setting in each panel’s sort order configuration:

[image: Screenshot of the panel sort order settings, with “Case sensitive” highlighted]

To configure quick search to be globally case insensitive, you need to set `quick_search_mode` to 0. (0 is “Case insensitive”, 1 is “Case sensitive”, 2 is “Use panel sort mode”.)

Comment: Perfect, thanks Stephen! Is there a secret manual for more information on the ini options or did you discover this through use? :)

Comment: Unfortunately there isn’t, I checked [the source code](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/tree/master/src) ;-).